# How to replace emoticons yet after user write text and press space

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If user write text like :) , :( ect. on textarea, I want to it will be replace this text with emoticon just after user press key-board space. (like facebook replace emoticon).

In my below php code, replace emoticon after press submit. But I want, It will be replase also emoticon with a Clint-side java script.

my php:

```
function smileys($text){
// Smiley to image
$smileys = array(
    ':)' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-)' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':D' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-(' => '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-D' => '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'lol' => '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-|' => '<img src="smilies/undecided.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ';-)' => '<img src="smilies/wink.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
);

// Now you need find and replace
foreach($smileys as $search => $replace){
     $text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#",  $replace, $text);
return $text;
    }
}
// My others code

echo ''.smileys($description).'';
```

I collected this JavaScript which start working after press space key, but I cannot have any idea how to write this full script for work in progress to replace.

```
    $('#comment').keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        var comment = $('#comment').val()
        //What will be here, I can't understand !!!
    }
});
```

my textarea

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var smileys = {
  ':)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ':-)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ':D': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ':-(': '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ':-D': '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  'lol': '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ':-|': '<img src="smilies/undecided.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
  ';-)': '<img src="smilies/wink.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chat > textarea").attr("disabled", false); //enable the box on page load
  $(".chat > textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
})

function smilyMe(msg) {
  //smiley replace
  return msg.replace(/(\:\)|\:-\)|\:D|\:-D|\blol\b|\:-\||\:-\(|\;-\))/g, function(all) {
    return smileys[all] || all;
  });
}
```

```css
div.chat {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
div.chat > div {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #939393;
  padding: 2px 10px 10px 10px;
}
div.chat > div > div {
  color: #939393;
  font-size: 9px;
}
div.chat > textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <div>
    <div>Preview</div>
  </div>
  <textarea disabled placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>

</div>
```

Use my `smilyMe` function.

However you can't attach images to a textarea. So I implemented a preview function.

Comment: You can change the replace function to loop over smileys' array to create the regex instead of making it hardcoded.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer yes that would be a nice addition.